# Error mapping dapper with an enum + sqlserver

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, mapping, dapper, sqlclient

I have a class:

```
   public class Member
{
    #region public property

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string OtherPhone { get; set; }
   ==> public AccountState AccountState { get; set; }
    public byte SiteId { get; set; }
    public int? GodFatherId { get; set; }
```

}

in this class , i have an enum 
`public enum AccountState
    {
        NotActivated = 0,
        Activated = 1,
        Desactived = 2,
        BlackListed = 3,
        ActivatedWithoutMailInvitation = 5
    }`

To acces to database: i'm using this class:

```
  public sealed class DbContext : IDbContext
{
    private bool disposed;
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public DbContext(string connectionString)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);

            return connection;
        }
    }

    public IDbTransaction CreateOpenedTransaction()
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            Connection.Open();
        return Connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteProcedure<T>(string procedure, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        return Dapper.SqlMapper.Query<T>(connection, procedure, param, transaction,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }

    public int ExecuteProcedure(string procedure, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        return Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(connection, procedure, param, transaction,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("** Disposing DbContext");

        if (disposed) return;

        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Dispose();
            connection = null;
        }

        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

My repository call the dbcontext like this:

```
public Member GetMemberId(int memberId, IDbTransaction transacion = null)
        {
            var memberResult = _dbContext.ExecuteProcedure<Member>(MemberProcedures.P_Select, new { MemberId = memberId }).SingleOrDefault();
            return memberResult;
        }
        public void SaveMember(Member memberToSave, IDbTransaction transacion = null)
        {
            _dbContext.ExecuteProcedure(MemberProcedures.P_AddMember,
                new
                {
                    LastName = memberToSave.LastName,
                    FirstName = memberToSave.FirstName,
                    InitialEmail = memberToSave.Email,
                    Password=memberToSave.Password,
                    Email=memberToSave.Email,
                    Mobile=memberToSave.Mobile,
                    Fax=memberToSave.Fax,
                    OtherPhone=memberToSave.OtherPhone,
                    AccountStateId = (int)memberToSave.AccountState,
                    BirthDate = memberToSave.BirthDate,
                    Civility = memberToSave.Civility
                });
        }
```

in my test class,i add a member to the database

```
  Member memberToInsert = new Member()
            {
                Civility = "Monsieur",
                Email = "xxxxxx@yopmail.com",
                Password = "password",
                FirstName = "xxxx",
                LastName = "xxx",
                Site = new Site() { Id = 1 },
                BirthDate = new DateTime(1988,02,02),
                AccountState = AccountState.Activated,
                GodFatherId = 1
            };

            _memberRepository.SaveMember(memberToInsert);
```

the member is saved into the database with `accountstate=1`

but when i execute:

```
Member memberGetted = _memberRepository.GetMemberId(1824);
```

I Get a memeber with a account.state=desactivated (value 0)
The stored procedure exexuted in msss is correct and show `accountstate=1`

Any solution please to map accountstate with the correct value of the enum?

Comment: What data type is AccountState in your database?

Comment: I have a  AccountStateId and type is tinyint

Comment: Are you swalling any DataExceptions? Mapping a tinyint to a int (your enum) should cause one.

Comment: Just to be explicit - you can do this simply by adding `: byte` onto the enum declaration: `public enum AccountState : byte { ... }`

Comment: it's true i can use : byte but in the case of smallint=int16 i can't do public enum AccountState : int16 { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a mapping issue.

The default enum type in C# is `int`, `tinyint` maps to the `CLR` type of `byte` so you'll either have to change your `enum` to `byte` or change the sql server data type accordingly.